# How to run TestNG file which is hosted on different server using MAVEN

Tags: java, maven, testng

I want my POM XML to choose TestNG XML which is hosted on different server .
Basically I have integrated my project with jenkins.  But i want to change the groupings ( BVT, Sanity , Regression) very frequently , this requires the checkin-checkout of TestNG XML file. 
Instead I want host XML file on some server and Maven/Projects  reads server .

Thanks and Regards
Sudarshan

Comment: Why not making different files which can be controlled by profiles...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use beanshell to make groups configurable - details [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell)

Make the changes in your single testng xml file and then run mvn test with -Dgroups=whatever

You can create different jobs for different groups.